# Filters are not showing in grid

Tags: javascript, java, extjs

I am trying to impliment filters in my grid but I am unable to do it. Please help me to solve it as i am new to Extjs.

I am using sencha fiddle to run this and when i tried to impement filter in grid as 
"**features : [filters]**"

please look to this also

```
Ext.require([
'Ext.grid.*',
'Ext.data.*',
'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
'Ext.toolbar.Paging']);

filters = {
    ftype: 'filters',
    encode: encode, 
   local: local,

    filters: [{
    type: 'numeric',
    dataIndex: 'Id'
}, {
    type: 'string',
    dataIndex: 'fname'
}, {
    type: 'string',
    dataIndex: 'lname'
}, {
    type: 'date',
    dataIndex: 'date'
},{
    type: 'numeric',
    dataIndex: 'age'
},/*{
    type: 'string',
    dataIndex: 'genderId'
}*/,{
    type: 'string',
    dataIndex: 'email'
},{
    type: 'numeric',
    dataIndex: 'phone'
}]
};
```

// grid

```
title       : 'Employee table',
              xtype       : 'grid',
              stripRows   : true,
              columnLines : true,
              store       : Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
              width       :'100%',
              features    : [filters]


columns: 
              [
                   {
                    header : 'ID',  dataIndex: 'Id', flex:0.5 ,filterable: true,
                    editor: 
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    header : 'First Name',  dataIndex: 'fname', flex:1 ,sortable : false,filterable: true,
                    filter: 
                    {
                        type: 'string'
                    },
                    editor: 
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                 },
                  {
                    header : 'Last Name',  dataIndex: 'lname', flex:1,filterable: true,
                    editor: 
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    header : 'DOB',  dataIndex: 'date', flex:1,filterable: true, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
                    editor: 
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                },
                  {
                    header : 'Gender',  dataIndex: 'genderId', flex:0.5,
                    editor: 
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    header : 'Age',  dataIndex: 'age', flex:0.5,filterable: true,
                    editor: 
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    header : 'Country',  dataIndex: 'country', flex:1,
                    editor: 
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    header : 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:2,filterable: true,
                    editor: 
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    header : 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', flex:1,filterable: true,
                    editor: 
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                  }
              ],
```

Comment: Some resources are missing it seems. Can you do app refresh and try again.

Comment: Did you checked Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature this file exist or not? Also which  Ext JS version are you using?

Comment: yes the plugin is present and i am using 4.2.1 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using extjs 6 version , then below code is useful for you.
You have to give 'gridfilters' plugin to grid to display filters.

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title : 'Employee table',
            stripRows   : true,
            columnLines : true,
            store       : Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
            width       :'100%',
            plugins: ['gridfilters'],

```
        columns: 
          [
               {
                header : 'ID',  dataIndex: 'Id', flex:0.5 ,filterable: true,
                editor: 
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
                filter: 
                {
                    type: 'numeric'
                } 
              },
              {
                header : 'First Name',  dataIndex: 'fname', flex:1 ,sortable : false,filterable: true,
                filter: 
                {
                    type: 'string'
                },
                editor: 
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                }
             },
              {
                header : 'Last Name',  dataIndex: 'lname', flex:1,filterable: true,
                editor: 
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
            filter: 
                {
                    type: 'string'
                }
              },
              {
                header : 'DOB',  dataIndex: 'date', flex:1,filterable: true, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
                editor: 
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
        filter: 
                {
                    type: 'date'
                }

            },
              {
                header : 'Gender',  dataIndex: 'genderId', flex:0.5,
                editor: 
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
        filter: 
                {
                    type: 'string'
                }
              },
              {
                header : 'Age',  dataIndex: 'age', flex:0.5,filterable: true,
                editor: 
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
        filter: 
                {
                    type: 'numeric'
                }
              },
              {
                header : 'Country',  dataIndex: 'country', flex:1,
                editor: 
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
        filter: 
                {
                    type: 'numeric'
                }
              },
              {
                header : 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:2,filterable: true,
                editor: 
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
        filter: 
                {
                    type: 'string'
                }
              },
              {
                header : 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', flex:1,filterable: true,
                editor: 
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
        filter: 
                {
                    type: 'numeric'
                }
              }
          ]
    });
```

Running example is on link [Grid Filters](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bnp)

Comment: thank you Shrinatha it worked but thing is when i tried to insert  my variable  "filter" in features inside grid it won't work, can you please tell me why

Comment: try to set path loader . Give path of ux folder from your project to loader       `Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ux');` you can refer example [http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/extjs-build/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html]   . Also give values to local and encode config as boolean.